# How to properly send JSON data to a phx phoenix API

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working on a Phoenix / phx API written using Elixir, and I am trying to test the functionality of the JSON API using Postman.  I'm sending JSON data to the API to hopefully create a new user, but phx is giving me the following error.

```
Phoenix.ActionClauseError at POST /api/users
```

Not sure where the problem lies exactly, so I'll post the router and the controller for the phx project.

**router.ex**

```
defmodule KegCopRAPI.Web.Router do
  use KegCopRAPI.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
    plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader, realm: "Bearer"
    plug Guardian.Plug.LoadResource
  end

  scope "/", KegCopRAPI.Web do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  scope "/api", KegCopRAPI.Web do
    pipe_through :api

    post "/sessions", SessionController, :create
    delete "/sessions", SessionController, :delete
    post "/sessions/refresh", SessionController, :refresh

    resources "/users", UserController, except: [:show, :index, :new, :edit]
  end
end
```

**user_controller.ex**

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    # with {:ok, %User{} = user} <- Accounts.create_user(user_params) do
    changeset = User.registration_changeset(%User{}, user_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        new_conn = Guardian.Plug.api_sign_in(conn, user, :access)
        jwt = Guardian.Plug.current_token(new_conn)
        # conn
        # |> put_status(:created)
        # |> put_resp_header("location", user_path(conn, :show, user))
        # |> render("show.json", user: user)
        new_conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> render(KegCopRAPI.SessionView, "show.json", user: user, jwt: jwt)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(KegCopRAPI.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

The entire project can be found [here](https://github.com/ipatch/kegcopr_api/tree/experimental-user-model)
Any and all help would greatly be appreciated.

I'm sending data to the API with the following Postman settings,
[image: postman settings]

The complete error message below,

```
[info] POST /api/users
[debug] Processing with KegCopRAPI.Web.UserController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"email" => "foo@example.com", "password" => "[FILTERED]", "username" => "foo"}
  Pipelines: [:api]
[info] Sent 400 in 10ms
[debug] ** (Phoenix.ActionClauseError) could not find a matching KegCopRAPI.Web.UserController.create clause
to process request. This typically happens when there is a
parameter mismatch but may also happen when any of the other
action arguments do not match. The request parameters are:

  %{"email" => "foo@example.com", "password" => "password", "username" => "foo"}

    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/web/controllers/user_controller.ex:14: KegCopRAPI.Web.UserController.create(%Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{}, before_send: [#Function<1.33581574/1 in Plug.Logger.call/2>, #Function<0.72433304/1 in Phoenix.LiveReloader.before_send_inject_reloader/2>], body_params: %{"email" => "foo@example.com", "password" => "password", "username" => "foo"}, cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}, halted: false, host: "localhost", method: "POST", owner: #PID<0.2357.0>, params: %{"email" => "foo@example.com", "password" => "password", "username" => "foo"}, path_info: ["api", "users"], path_params: %{}, peer: {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 59852}, port: 4000, private: %{KegCopRAPI.Web.Router => {[], %{}}, :guardian_default_resource => nil, :phoenix_action => :create, :phoenix_controller => KegCopRAPI.Web.UserController, :phoenix_endpoint => KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint, :phoenix_format => "json", :phoenix_layout => {KegCopRAPI.Web.LayoutView, :app}, :phoenix_pipelines => [:api], :phoenix_router => KegCopRAPI.Web.Router, :phoenix_view => KegCopRAPI.Web.UserView, :plug_session_fetch => #Function<1.131660147/1 in Plug.Session.fetch_session/1>}, query_params: %{}, query_string: "", remote_ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, req_cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}, req_headers: [{"cache-control", "no-cache"}, {"postman-token", "da608739-758b-40d7-bdef-23b3c2a63bed"}, {"content-type", "application/json"}, {"user-agent", "PostmanRuntime/3.0.11-hotfix.2"}, {"accept", "*/*"}, {"host", "localhost:4000"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate"}, {"content-length", "76"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"}], request_path: "/api/users", resp_body: nil, resp_cookies: %{}, resp_headers: [{"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"}, {"x-request-id", "slfdhshckenp3dinlqr22m5nlakhoaq4"}, {"access-control-allow-origin", "*"}, {"access-control-expose-headers", ""}, {"access-control-allow-credentials", "true"}, {"vary", ""}], scheme: :http, script_name: [], secret_key_base: "fIEpvi5ujSQEKgmkRpt83KiLPq068sSmvFKlWFZyNpi3nkNmUtYO24Em6cXIUblZ", state: :unset, status: nil}, %{"email" => "foo@example.com", "password" => "password", "username" => "foo"})
    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: KegCopRAPI.Web.UserController.action/2
    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: KegCopRAPI.Web.UserController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/web/endpoint.ex:1: KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint.instrument/4
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:277: Phoenix.Router.__call__/1
    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/web/endpoint.ex:1: KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
    (kegcopr_api) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/web/endpoint.ex:1: KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint.call/2
    (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
    (cowboy) /opt/elixir/kegcopr_api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? Also, do you have the Content-Type etc right in the Postman request?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute.  And I set the content-type to JSON (application/json)

Comment: Your data should be like this: `{"user": { "username": ..., ... } }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the data from the map inside the `"user"` key, you need to put all the fields under the `"user"` key in the request, like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "username": "foo",
    "email": "foo@example.com",
    "password": "password"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you are pattern-matching

```
"user" => user_params
```

So, you have to put the user params under the user key:

```
"user": {
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    ...
}
```